# update of a column based on max date and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i have three tables orders, orders_delivered, orders_delivered_sta
and the data in the three tables look like

table orders

```
orders_id 
 10
 11                      
 12
 13
```

table orders_delivered

```
orders_delivered_id    orders_id
       10                 1000                                  
       10                 1001                                  
       11                 1002                            
       12                 1003
       12                 1004
       13                 1005 
       13                 1006
       13                 1007
```

table orders_delivered_sta

```
  orders_delivered_sta_id   orders_delivered_id   date     now_ind
            1                  1000             02/11/2011   0
            2                  1000             01/10/2006   0
            3                  1000             09/13/2011   0
            4                  1001             01/19/2010   0
            5                  1001             02/21/2011   0
            6                  1002             02/11/2009   0
            7                  1002             08/27/2010   0
            8                  1003             07/15/2012   0
            9                  1004             03/09/2007   0
            10                 1010             10/01/2010   0
            11                 1011             03/27/2011   0
            12                 1012             07/25/2010   0
            13                 1013             09/18/2004   0
```

so i need to update orders_delivered_sta table such that now_ind should be 1 for the max date of one  orders_delivered_id
like for one orders_delivered_id 1000 the max date is 09/13/2011 for this set of orders_delivered_id and date (1000,09/13/2011)  the now_ind should be 1 and if the column orders_delivered_id has one and only one id then that should be changed to 1

there is some data in orders_delivered_sta table which are not in orders and orders_delivered tables those need not to be changed. the orders_delivered_id which are in oreders_delivered table only needs to change

so the desired output should look like

table orders_delivered_sta

```
 orders_delivered_sta_id   orders_delivered_id   date     now_ind
            1                  1000             02/11/2011   0
            2                  1000             01/10/2006   0
            3                  1000             09/13/2011   1
            4                  1001             01/19/2010   0
            5                  1001             02/21/2011   1
            6                  1002             02/11/2009   0
            7                  1002             08/27/2010   1
            8                  1003             07/15/2012   1
            9                  1004             03/09/2007   1
           10                 1010             10/01/2010   0
           11                 1011             03/27/2011   0
           12                 1012             07/25/2010   0
           13                 1013             09/18/2004   0
```

table structure:

```
create table orders
(
 order_id int primary key  
)

insert into orders select 10
insert into orders select 11                      
insert into orders select 12
insert into orders select 13

create table orders_delivered
( 
  orders_delivered_id int primary key, 
   orders_id int FOREIGN KEY(orders_id)REFERENCES orders (orders_id)
)
insert into orders_delivered select   1000,10                                  
insert into orders_delivered select   1001,10                                  
insert into orders_delivered select   1002,11                            
insert into orders_delivered select   1003,12
insert into orders_delivered select   1004,12
insert into orders_delivered select   1005,13 
insert into orders_delivered select   1006,13
insert into orders_delivered select   1007,13

create table orders_delivered_sta
( 
  orders_delivered_sta_id int primary key, 
   orders_delivered_id int FOREIGN KEY(orders_delivered_id)REFERENCES orders_delivered (orders_delivered_id), 
   date char(10),
  now_ind int
)

insert into orders_delivered_sta select 1,1000,'02/11/2011', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 2,1000,'01/10/2006', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 3,1000,'09/13/2011', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 4,1001,'01/19/2010', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 5,1001,'02/21/2011', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 6,1002,'02/11/2009', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 7,1002,'08/27/2010', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 8,1003,'07/15/2012', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 9,1004,'03/09/2007', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 10,1010,'10/01/2010', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 11,1011,'03/27/2011', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 12,1012,'07/25/2010', 0
insert into orders_delivered_sta select 13,1013,'09/18/2004', 0
```

Comment: Your orders_delivered table has a PK on a field that you are duplicating! Besides, why do you provide those 3 tables if the only one needed is orders_delivered_sta?

Comment: because orders_delivered_sta has some more data which are not in orders table

Comment: All 3 of the solutions posted would work, however I don't understand why you would want to update a table based on the MAX value in this way, you would have to perform the update everytime a new row was added to ensure the data is correct and up to date. A view with a realtime calculated Now_Ind column on would make more sense. I would have posted a solution however there are discrepencies in your question that have left me baffled...

Answer (score 6):

You could use a CTE and a window `MAX()`:

```
;
WITH max_dates AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    max_date = MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY orders_delivered_id)
  FROM orders_delivered_sta
  WHERE orders_delivered_id IN (SELECT orders_delivered_id FROM orders_delivered)
)
UPDATE max_dates
SET now_ind = 1
WHERE date = max_date
```

References:

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE    orders_delivered_sta
SET       now_ind = 1
WHERE     orders_delivered_sta_id IN(
          SELECT     orders_delivered_sta_id
          FROM       (
                      SELECT     orders_delivered_sta_id,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY orders_delivered_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS num
                      FROM       orders_delivered_sta) AS T
          WHERE      T.num = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query in MySQL, but translating it to SQL-Server should be straight forward as I am using plain SQL. Notice I have changed the date to be in a different form (YYYY-MM-DD) to avoid castings from string to date.

```
update t3
set t3.now_ind = 1
where t3.orders_delivered_sta_id in (
    select distinct t1.orders_delivered_sta_id from t1
    left join (
        select t2.orders_delivered_id, max(t2.adate) as MaxDate from t2
        group by t2.orders_delivered_id
    ) t2 on (t1.orders_delivered_id = t2.orders_delivered_id) and (t1.adate = t2.MaxDate)
    where t2.orders_delivered_id is not null
) and exists (
    select * from o1
    join od1 on (o1.order_id = od1.orders_delivered_id)
    where (t3.orders_delivered_id = od1.orders_id)
)
```

Here is an [example](http://www.sqlize.com/XwFLAfHMm6)

Hope this helps

PS: You did need those 3 tables... I'll read questions better next time :)

Comment: thx for the example... but if the orders_delivered_id which is present in orders_delivered_sta and that is not in orders_delivered table( cleralt stating example oredrs_delivered_id 1010 is present in orders_delivered_sta table and that 1010 doesnt exists in orders_delivered table) this one should not be affected in orders_delivered_sta table

Comment: You're right. I didn't pay attention to the question. My bad :) Take a look at the code now. Basically I added the EXISTS clause you where talking about.

Comment: Welcome! Please, consider setting your question as answered :)